# How to Encrypt Privatekey with another Publickey?

Tags: go, encryption, rsa

I have service that runs in background, manages cryptographic keys. I want to transfer those keys from one end to another.

This transfer includes RSA's Private Key also. During this transfer I encrypt actual Key value with some other public key. AES "key value" encryption working as expected. But RSA private key transfer it throws following error.

> error=crypto/rsa: message too long for RSA public key size

I understand that only limited amount of bytes can be encrypted by particular length of key length.

> For 3072 bit public key  it shows, "Data must not be longer than 373
> bytes"
>
> For 4096 bit public key it shows, "Data must not be longer than 501
> bytes"

Reference -> https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/rsa-encryption-decryption

But in my case, actual key length of private key is 1624(2048 key length). To encrypt this I need to create key pair with 15360 encrypt key with public key(15360)and it is working.

But I've key supported length up to 15360 in my service.  So again to transfer this length of private key I need to create again 115200(i'm not sure about this length) of length keypair? Whether this approach is correct or there is any other way for this problem ?

Comment: To encrypt data with your size (> 15.000 bytes) use **hybrid encryption** -> a) create a random aes key, encrypt the [long] RSA key with AES-GCM mode and then encrypt the aes-key with the RSA public key [the second one from another system]. For decryption go backwards: decrypt the aes-key with the private key, decrypt the [encrypted] long rsa key and you are fine.

Comment: If you think this is madness, you could use PKCS#12 and PKCS#8 specifications to add another few layers of encoding rather than encryption :P